# how to make realm CRUD operation in separate swift file?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am a beginner in iOS development and in programming, I am trying to make a swift file that contain realm CRUD operation called `RealmService` , so I don't have to write do catch block and try! realm all over the place, like my code below

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class RealmService {

    var realm = try! Realm()

    func save(_ object: Object) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save \(object) in realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func load(_ object: Object) -> Results<Object>? {
        return realm.objects(object.self)
    }

    func update(_ object: Object, with dictionary: [String: Any?]) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                for (key, value) in dictionary {
                    object.setValue(value, forKey: key)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to update \(object) in realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func delete(_ object: Object) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.delete(object)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to delete \(object) in realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

but in the `load` method, I get an error in the line `realm.objects(object.self)` , it is said

> Cannot convert value of type 'Object' to expected argument type
>   'Object.Type'

[image]

I think I make mistake when insert object.self in the realm.objects. it should be element.type, but I dont have a clue what is this element type like this picture
[image]

how to load data from realm? sadly i just know a little bit from youtube tutorial by using  `realm.objects(object.self)`

Comment: What is `Results<Object>`?

Comment: I am a newbie, but as far as i know, if we load the data from realm database, the data type shall be Result<Object>

Comment: Right. It looks like the returned value (`realm.objects(object.self`)) is not of type `Result<Object>`.

Comment: I think I make mistake when insert  object.self in the realm.objects. it should be element.type, but I dont have a clue what is this element type like this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVIs6.png

Comment: Hover mouse over variable, press option key and click on variable. Should show you the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the work of select through an object and this is a mistake because it is required of the type of object `Element.Type` and not the object itself

try to use this

```
 func load<T: Object>(ofType: T.Type) -> Results<T> {

            return realm.objects(T.self)

    }
```

call this func

```
class MyObject: Object {
     ...
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    ...

   }
  .....
  ream.objects(MyObject.self)
```

Answer (score 2):

I use ReamManager with CRUD like this:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class RealmManager {

    private let NotificationError = Notification.Name.Realm.realmErrorNotification

    var realm = try! Realm()

    func create<T: Object>(_ object: T) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object, update: true)
            }
        } catch {
            post(error)
        }
    }

    func create<T: Object>(_ objects: [T]) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(objects, update: true)
            }
        } catch {
            post(error)
        }
    }

    func read<T: Object>(_ object: T.Type) -> Results<T> {
        let result = realm.objects(object.self)
        return result
    }

    func update<T: Object>(_ object: T, with dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                for (key, value) in dictionary {
                    object.setValue(value, forKey: key)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            post(error)
        }
    }

    func delete<T: Object>(_ object: T) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.delete(object)
            }
        } catch {
            post(error)
        }
    }

    func post(_ error: Error) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotificationError, object: error)
    }

    func observeRealErrors(in viewController: UIViewController, complation: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NotificationError, object: viewController, queue: nil) { (notification) in
            complation(notification.object as? Error)
        }
    }

    func stopObserveRealErrors(in viewController: UIViewController) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(viewController, name: NotificationError, object: nil)
    }
}
```

maybe that's exactly what you wanted